# No automorphisms of order $p^2$

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group, direct-product, general-linear-group

Let $H$ be the group of integers mod p, under addition, where
$p$ is a prime number. Suppose that n is an integer satisfying $1 ≤ n ≤ p$,
and let G be the group $H × H × · · · ×H $($n$ factors). Show that $G$ has no
automorphism of order $p^2$.

This is a problem of Berkeley spring $83$ prelim exam. The same question had been asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2348097/order-of-an-automorphism), but there were no answers. Therefore I am asking it again. Can anyone please help me out ?

I have understand the comments of the old problem. Sylow-$p$ subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$ will have order $p^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. I am unable to proceed further from here.

Comment: can you identify some matrices in a Sylow $p$-subgroup?  One approach is to look directly at its structure.

Comment: yes I know that the set of upper triangular matrices forms a sylow p subgroup in $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_p)$. As there are $p^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ such matrices.

Comment: OK, so you need to show that if you raise one of those to the power $p$, you get the identity...

Comment: Sorry it should have been "upper triangular matrices with diagonal entries 1". Thanks a lot. Let me try

Comment: The characteristic polynomial will be $(x-1)^p$ and clearly it is equal to $x^p-1$ after modulo p. And hence for any such matrix $A$, We will have $A^P=I$.

Comment: ...or avoiding the char poly machinery, such a matrix is $I+N$ where $N$ is strictly upper triangular $k\times k$ with $k\leqslant p$, so $N^p=0$. Maybe you could write an answer to the other question

Comment: Use `$\le$` for $\le$ and `$\times$` for $\times$.

Comment: @MatthewTowers How to conclude after this? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F_p$ be the field with $p$ elements, let $n$ be an integer such that $1\leq n\leq p$. Your group $G$ is the abelian group underlying the $F_p$ vector space $F_p^n$, and an automorphism of that abelian group is the same as an automorphism of that vector space. This means that your problem is the same as:

> Show that no automorphism of the $F_p$-vector space $F_p^n$ has order $p^2$.

Now let $f:F_p^n\to F_p^n$ be an automorphism of order $p^2$. Then $f^{p^2}=I$, so the polynomial $X^{p^2}-1$ vanishes on $f$. That polynomial factors as $(X-1)^{p^2}$, and this tells us that the linear map $f-1$ is nilpotent. As the dimension of $F_p^n$ is $n$, of course, the nilpotency index is at most $n$, and therefore $(f-1)^n=0$. In particular, we have that $f^p-1=(f-1)^p=0$, and the order of $f$ is at most $p$: this is a contradiction.